# Why does adding a smoothing penalty here cause COBS to go haywire?

Tags: r, splines

I'm using [`cobs`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cobs/index.html) to do some interpolation.

I want to impose concavity, monotonicity, and some boundary constraints on the interpolated function.

This has been working quite well in general, but for some sets of points, it fails.

Here's the sample data causing me issues:

```
x = c(8, 9, 15, 8, 2, 8, 14, 20, 8, 8, 3, 1, 1, 17, 
      8, 2, 3, 17, 14, 10, 5, 6, 7, 10, 22, 1, 7, 6, 
      3, 14, 22, 8, 28, 3, 17, 5, 6, 7, 7, 6, 3, 8, 2, 
      8, 14, 11, 9, 7, 11, 23, 11, 22, 23, 2, 12, 29, 
      22, 16, 8, 3, 27, 3, 3, 22, 28, 29, 4, 4, 3, 12, 
      13, 3, 12, 12, 12, 7, 5, 6, 23, 4, 21, 27, 28, 29, 
      7, 3, 7, 27, 14, 2, 2, 5, 17, 2, 19, 8, 22, 30, 
      27, 26, 22, 30, 22, 8, 21, 28, 22, 13, 13, 24, 30, 
      23, 19, 30, 28, 23, 30, 19, 24, 21, 26, 30, 28, 6, 
      24, 30, 19, 26, 30, 29, 30, 18, 19, 24, 23, 24, 23, 
      28, 22, 9, 8, 22, 12, 13, 30, 4, 6, 22, 22, 19, 
      27, 17, 10, 21, 23, 14, 23, 30, 27, 25, 11, 23, 25, 
      19, 30, 28, 22, 26, 22, 28, 17, 27, 28, 30, 30, 29, 
      23, 8, 23, 6, 29, 27, 25, 28, 8, 26, 29, 18, 29, 27, 21)

y = c(4187, 6117, 2457, 3550, 3248, 2842, 7228, 1789, 4187, 
      7030, 6777, 1843, 1843, 7554, 3550, 1456, 6676, 7454, 
      6785, 7092, 3629, 3503, 7007, 4046, 7469, 819, 6938, 
      982, 306, 4338, 7996, 4187, 7761, 4074, 7454, 3629, 
      3503, 7007, 6938, 982, 306, 7030, 3248, 2842, 7228, 
      7236, 6117, 6937, 7241, 7842, 4161, 7294, 7620, 7005, 
      7398, 7760, 2172, 7541, 6616, 6596, 4441, 1762, 6727, 
      7628, 7761, 2476, 3466, 6926, 6619, 7136, 7377, 6841, 
      7323, 4310, 7320, 1779, 7068, 6857, 4516, 3611, 8151, 
      7773, 7797, 8164, 3812, 4088, 7189, 7682, 7611, 6806, 
      3233, 4785, 8322, 4743, 4293, 7199, 7760, 8223, 8318, 
      8326, 7763, 8063, 7836, 7199, 7801, 4890, 7325, 7598, 
      7598, 7767, 4592, 8081, 4670, 8293, 8005, 8152, 4594, 
      2419, 7770, 7801, 8331, 8005, 4797, 6942, 7767, 4592, 
      4670, 8288, 4594, 8121, 8186, 8041, 2419, 7770, 8128, 
      7953, 8062, 4890, 7325, 1974, 7199, 7760, 7557, 7976, 
      8223, 4112, 7583, 7763, 2524, 4293, 8203, 4226, 7496, 
      7966, 7935, 7574, 2649, 8300, 8059, 8049, 7754, 2672, 
      8167, 7646, 7982, 7911, 7802, 7810, 1961, 7780, 7832, 
      4598, 4506, 4635, 8064, 8122, 8219, 1973, 7776, 1924, 
      8117, 8183, 8197, 8170, 7277, 8278, 8176, 8057, 8065, 
      8064, 4628)
```

Even standard `cobs` does a pretty good job:

```
library(cobs)
plot(cobs(x, y))
```

[image: plain]

Note that all of the constraints appear to be satisfied by the unconstrained solution -- it's increasing, concave, above 0 at 0, and doesn't get too large.

So it's no surprise that introducing these constraints doesn't change anything:

```
end_cons = rbind(c(1, 0, 0),
                 c(-1, 30, 117146))
#identical to above plot
plot(cobs(x, y, constraint = c('increase', 'concave'),
          pointwise = end_cons, knots.add = TRUE, 
          repeat.delete.add=TRUE))
```

However, the second we ask `cobs` to do $\lambda$ selection ($\lambda$ being the penalty weight in the objective $L(y, g(x)) + \lambda \max_x g''(x)$ used to fit the splines coefficients), things go wild:

[image: problem]

It seems to me that, given the success of the fit absent constraints & absent $\lambda$ selection, the algorithm should be successful in fitting something close to the $\lambda = 0$ solution.

Comment: @MartinMächler any suggestions?